# Field extensions and subfields

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let K ⊆ L is a field extension and S ⊆ L be a non empty set. We define
the subfield of L generated by K ∪ S, denoted by K(S), to be the smallest subfield of L containing K ∪ S. Moreover, K(S) is the intersection of all the
subfields of L containing K ∪ S. In this case, we say that K(S) is the field
obtained from K by adjoining the set S.
Similarly, We define the subring of L generated by K ∪ S, denoted by
K[S], to be the smallest subring of L containing K ∪ S. Clearly, K[S] is the
intersection of all the subrings of L containing K ∪ S.

Why can we write this
K ⊆ K[S] ⊆ K(S) ⊆ L.??????

Please help

Comment: Which inclusion is an issue for you?

Comment: The second, and i have another question, how can SUK be a subfield

Comment: $K(S)$ is the *smallest field containing $K \cup S$*. It needn’t be $K \cup S$ itself. In particular, it is a ring containing $K \cup S$, so contains the smallest ring containing $K \cup S$ which is $K[S]$.

Comment: If i take for example the field R and i take a subset S of this field such that it contains an irrational number. Now Q is a subfield of R, how can i make up another field generated by a set containing an irrational number in Q.             I cant find an ivertiblr element for this irrational number in Q, nor this irrational number can be contained in Q

Comment: 1) Please use Mathjax, there’s an explanation in the meta. 2) For your specific example, if you can’t make the inverse with the operations and elements, well, you add it. You consider the *intersection* of *all* the *subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ that contain $\mathbb{Q} \cup S$. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}(\{\pi\})$ is the set of the $F(\pi)$, where $F$ is a rational fraction with rational coefficients. The philosophy is – if you lack an inverse, or the result of an addition or a multiplication, just add it to the field!